# Why is Jenkins making temp files that are binaries?

Tags: jenkins

I have an installation of Jenkins on my server I use for continuous integration of a beta website. The configuration is pretty simple, I just use the proper directory in `/var/www/` as the workspace, and Git with the Git plugin for source control.

I recently installed [CSF](http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html) on the server, and it keeps reporting the temp files Jenkins is making are 'suspicious'. Here is a log of the most recent report:

```
Time:   Mon Aug 24 16:11:08 2015 -0400
File:   /tmp/jffi6688931929611009979.tmp
Reason: Linux Binary
Owner:  jenkins:jenkins (112:120)
Action: No action taken
```

The file in question appears to legitimately be an executable file. **My question is, why is Jenkins creating temporary executable files?**

*Note: The server is 100% PHP based, Jenkins should not create any executables from it!*

<strike>The files seem to be created whenever Jenkins builds a project, even though the build step just puts the password into the correct config file.</strike> Nope, they randomly pop up around twice an hour or so.

`file` output on one of the files:

```
$ file /tmp/jffi6688931929611009979.tmp
/tmp/jffi6688931929611009979.tmp: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

Plugin list:

- Ant Plugin
- Build Monitor View
- Credentials Binding Plugin
- Credentials Plugin
- CVS Plug-in
- disk-usage plugin
- External Monitor Job Type Plugin
- GIT client plugin
- GIT plugin
- Javadoc Plugin
- JUnit Plugin
- LDAP Plugin
- Mailer Plugin
- Matrix Authorization Strategy Plugin
- Matrix Project Plugin
- Maven Integration plugin
- OWASP Markup Formatter Plugin
- PAM Authentication plugin
- Plain Credentials Plugin
- SCM API Plugin
- Script Security Plugin
- SSH Credentials Plugin
- SSH Slaves plugin
- Translation Assistance plugin
- Windows Slaves Plugin
- Workflow: Step API

Comment: Have you tried looking at the contents of the file ?

Comment: They're binary files (Like Windows's .exe). As far as I can see, they just contain random data, and I'm too scared to try running them. I'll see if I can make a VM to run them on that isn't connected to the internet.

Comment: What does the 'file' command report those files as being?

Comment: An ELF (*nix executable) - Added the full result to the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I discovered the problem. The file in question was a Jenkins update. I didn't notice that the file was improperly not getting deleted, and all the alerts were about the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is a Java program.

Java programs requiring native libraries *may* extract the native .so or .dll file from its .jar files into /tmp to be able to properly load the native library.

I don't think that standard Jenkins would include plugins which require native libraries. Maybe one of the plugins you installed requires native libraries?

Comment: Added my plugin list. Do any look like culprits? None of them do to me, especially since I've discovered these files are dropped randomly, not just during builds.